# Set conditonal default value of a field

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom form with a field...

```
function mh_integration_connect_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  $form['cat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Categories'),
    '#options' => $categories,
    '#default_value' => $params['cat'],
  );
}
```

as $param is not set before the form is submitted, so it show error for "Notice: Undefined index: cat".
I am wondering if we can set this default_value conditionally,

```
if(isset($params['cat'])) {
    '#default_value' => $params['cat'],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply want to remove this error and conditionally use the default value.

For this, you can also do one more thing in addition to this code

```
function mh_integration_connect_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  $form['cat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Categories'),
    '#options' => $categories,
    '#default_value' => isset($params['cat']) ? $params['cat'] : '',
  );
}
```

Hope it works for you! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
  $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  $form['cat'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Categories'),
    '#options' => $categories,
  );

  if(isset($params['cat'])) {
    $form['cat']['#default_value'] = $params['cat'];
  }
```

Comment: I too guess this should work, but it actuly recreates the field "$form['cat']['#default_value'] = $params['cat'];" means field is not visible as select.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. This line can't create a `select`. The creation of select is in the line 2.